# Add a subdomain into Route 53 and control all the subdomains under that subdomain from Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I would like to create a subdomain on Route 53 with DNS provided by GoDaddy and control all of it's subdomains from Route 53. E.g. Assume that I have purchased `example.com` on GoDaddy and created different records to point them to respective IP addresses where my services are hosted.

Without disturbing this setup, I want to add `service.example.com` on AWS Route 53 and control all of it's subdomains e.g. `test.service.example.com`,  `int.service.example.com`, `rel.service.example.com` from AWS itself without making any changes to Records (except for `service.example.com`) on GoDaddy.

I was referring to few video tutorials for doing the same but It's not explaining completely how to make this happen.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4FPZ29Trpw

Please note, I don't want to transfer my parent domain to AWS Route 53. I just want to have my subdomain and any subdomains unders this on AWS Route 53.

I would really appreciate any pointers to get me moving in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already configured an AWS Route 53 hosted zone for `service.example.com`, you'll need to create an NS record for `service.example.com` at GoDaddy, and populate that record with the Route 53 hosted zone nameserver names. You'll find these in the value for the NS record for the Route 53 hosted zone. For example:

```
ns-2027.awsdns-61.co.uk.
ns-1042.awsdns-02.org.
ns-819.awsdns-38.net.
ns-211.awsdns-26.com.
```

You can then create relevant records in Route 53 as required.

As ever with DNS, things may take time to propagate.

Comment: Thanks!!! This works like a charm for mapping against a single entry e.g. ns-2027.awsdns-61.co.uk :-) However, I'm not able to add multiple entries against this NS record on Go Daddy.

Comment: To answer my previous comments, for adding multiple values for a nameserver record on GoDaddy, you need to make multiple entries. Please refer this article https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/209564665-Example-step-1-for-GoDaddy-Delegation-of-your-subdomain